# Is there a hook before Next.js Hot Reload happens?

Tags: next.js

Each time the application Hot Reloads it creates a new database connection pool with `node-mysql2` to reuse DB connections. However when the application Hot Reloads a new pool is created. Over time this causes the RDBMS to reach its maximum number of connections (~300). How can I close the connection pool using a hook or another technique before Hot Reload abandons the app instance?

This is in the API section so front end context providers can't help.

```
event - build page: /api/order/listForUser
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
Connection pool was falsey. Created a new connection pool.
Released connection.
Released connection.
event - build page: /order/[orderId]
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
event - build page: /api/order/details
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
Connection pool was falsey. Created a new connection pool.
Released connection.
Released connection.
```

As you can see, each time an API "Page" is built, a new connection pool is created. That makes sense because the code is new, but is there any way to clean up my connection pool before this event occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **known nextjs issue** and happens only in development. You can try to create a global variable to hold the connection. (However, this does not work 100%, even if u use global.variable).

example psuedo code.

```
  let connection

    module.exports = () => {
      
          if (!connection) {
                connection = mysqlconnection(connection string)
                return connection
          } else {
                return connection
          }

          

    }
```

Comment: That pattern is how I have it now.. it works 0% . Could you link the known issue or what keywords I would use to find more about the issue?

Comment: you can use `global.connection` instead of `connection`, though I can tell you this is a issue whether you are in development, or if you deploy it on Vercel (serverless functions). I ended using nextJS as frontend and static generation, but use a separate expressJS app for all my api routes. It's cleaner, lighter weight, and avoided all these unnecessary issues. I've been using Nextjs for 10+ projects for last 3 years so I know it well.

Comment: `global.connection` does work, even between page reloads. Thank you!